# How to pass a list of arbitrary size to an OpenCL kernel

Tags: arguments, opencl

I have been fiddling with OpenCL recently, and I have run into a serious limitation: You cannot pass an array of pointers to a kernel.  This makes it difficult to pass an arbitrarily sized list of, say, images to a kernel.  I had a couple of thoughts toward this, and I was wondering if anybody could say for sure whether or not they would work, or offer better suggestions.

Let's say you had x image objects that you wanted to be passed to the kernel.  If they were all only 2D, one solution might be to pack them all into a 3D image, and just index the slices.  The problem with this is, if the images are different sizes, then space will be wasted, because the 3D image has to have the width of the widest image, the height of the tallest image, and the depth would be the number of images.

However, I was also thinking that when you pass a buffer object to a kernel, it appears in the kernel as a pointer.  If you had a kernel that took an arbitrary data buffer, and a buffer designated just for storing pointers, and then appended the pointer to the first buffer to the end of the second buffer, (provided there was enough allocated space of course) then maybe you could keep a buffer of pointers to other buffers on the device.  This buffer could then be passed to other kernels, which would then, with some interesting casting, be able to access these arbitrary buffers on the device.  The only problem is whether or not a given buffer pointer would remain the same throughout the life of the buffer.  Also, when you pass an image, you get a struct as an argument.  Now, does this struct actually have a home in device memory?  Or is it around just long enough to be passed to the kernel?  These things are important in that they would determine whether or not the pointer buffer trick would work on images too, assuming it would work at all.

Does anybody know if the buffer trick would work?  Are there any other ways anybody can think of to pass a list of arbitrary size to a kernel?

EDIT: The buffer trick does NOT work.  I have tested it.  I am not sure why exactly, but the pointers on the device don't seem to stay the same from one invocation to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing an array of pointers to a kernel does not make sense, because the pointers would point to host memory, which the OpenCL device does not know anything about. You would have to transfer the data to a device buffer and then pass the buffer pointer to the kernel. (There are some more complicated options with mapped/pinned memory and especially in the case of APUs, but they don't change the main fact, that host pointers are invalid on the device).

I can suggest one approach, although I have never actually used it myself. If you have a large device buffer preallocated, you could fill it up with images back to back from the host. Then call the kernel with the buffer and a list of offsets as arguments.

Comment: The idea is to use a kernel to save the pointers to device memory into another buffer on the device, not the host pointers.  Also, the problem with reading the images into serial buffers is that I don't get the hardware optimizations to speed up the image data access, although it is a workable solution if no other works.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy, and I've done it.  You don't use pointers, so much as references, and you do it like this.  In your kernel, you can provide two arguments:

```
kernel void(
   global float *rowoffsets,
   global float *data
) {
```

Now, in your host, you simply take your 2d data, copy it into a 1d array, and put the index of the start of each row into `rowoffsets`

For the last row, you add an additional rowoffset, pointing to one past the end of data.

Then in your kernel, to read the data from a row, you can do things like:

```
kernel void(
   global float *rowoffsets,
   global float *data,
   const int N
) {
    for( int n = 0; n < N; n++ ) {
        const int rowoffset = rowoffsets[n];
        const int rowlen = rowoffsets[n+1] - rowoffset;
        for( int col = 0; col < rowlen; col++ ) {
            // do stuff with data[rowoffset + col] here
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, how you're actually going to assign the data to each workitem is up to you, so whether you're using actual loops, or giving each workitem a single row and column is part of your own application design.